# JQGrid Grouping Rows at Multiple Levels with No Pagination Performance Degrade

Tags: javascript, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I have a requirement in which I need to group a JQGrid table in 5 different row levels and I am not allowed to use any pagination. So all the data need to show up. the table has 5000 rows in total. When I try to expand the rows the page is unresponsive and performance is really poor.
If I group only one level it seems ok to respond. Is there a way to insert rows as you expand the rows. I use onClickGroup function but it seems it reloads the table and still with grouping page gets stuck. Any help is appreciated.

I tried to load table with one level grouping and when I clcik the button I regrouped to 2 levels. but I lost the cursor and it reloaded the whole table. I was expecting only the selected row should be grouped. As I went down further grouping, it got slower and slower to respond. I expected it to be more responsive.

Comment: 5 k rows are very big value to be stored in local array for any grid and any other component. You can use the new indexedDB driver to load the data locally at client and the operate at it as it is from the server with pagination. As for the second requirement without to show your code how you do this we can not help.